# IntelliSense & _references.js support for files not included in the project

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, intellisense, references.js

I have a MVC project with several JavaScript script files. Some of these files need to be unit-tested. For that, we have a separate JS file. The test file is placed in the *Scripts* folder and is not included in the project (i.e. no reference in the `.csproj` file). All our script files are referenced in `_references.js`.

The test file, when opened from Visual Studio, does not have any IntelliSense support for the files include in the project; there is nor jQuery support, nor custom scripts support. Please note that Vanilla JS IntelliSense works.

Is there a way of enabling IntelliSense support from the files references in `_reference.js`, for JavaScript files that are not included in the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Mads Kristensen](http://madskristensen.net/post/the-story-behind-_referencesjs)

> There are several ways of implementing Intellisense for JavaScript. The three I remember being discussed were:
>   1. All .js files in the project are automatically included in Intellisense
>   2. Only .js files included on the same HTML pages are included
>   3. The user can manually reference other .js files

The solution then was to add `_references.js` as a specific reference at the begining of the file not included in the project.

```
/// <reference path="_references.js" />

//other JS code
```

This enables IntelliSense support for the `_references.js` file, which in turn enables IntelliSense for the files it references.